# Symfony-ux LiveComponent

Tags: symfony

I wanted to try Symfony-ux LIveComponent for a project, a small classic collectionType form with a delete button for each card, an add button to add cards as you go, fill in the generate fields and save everything with a save button.

I used a lot of help from symfony documentation, everything works except data saving, it's a bit annoying, the example I'm going to put below uses symfony documentation but it's not taken into account, maybe I forgot something, but in the current state of things I'm a bit lost.

If someone who has already used the LIve Component of symfony and had this problem would have some time, or just someone available for help it would be great :)

Note that I have no error, the ajax that is triggered is correct.
Here is the creation of my form and its save function:

```
 public Campaign $campaign;

protected function instantiateForm(): FormInterface
{
    return $this->createForm(ListMissionFormType::class, $this->campaign);
}

#[LiveAction]
public function save(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $this->submitForm();
    $this->validate();

    $mission = $this->getFormInstance()->getData();
    $entityManager->persist($mission);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', 'Modification enregistré');

    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'), Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);

}
```

Comment: Did you try dumping `$mission`, is it a doctrine entity ?

Comment: In the dump I have my $mission entity but without any modification on the modify fields.

Comment: This code looks good to me. What about your twig template?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$mission = $this->getForm()->getData();
```

Your IDE might complain (mine does) but it works :
[ux-live-component](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-live-component/current/index.html#submitting-the-form-via-a-liveaction)